# How to trigger build for changes in a subdirectory of a Git repo in buildbot

Tags: buildbot

Say you have a repo with this structure:

```
myrepo/project1
myrepo/project2
```

How do you configure buildbot so it only triggers build when there's update in myrepo/project1?

Following is sample config I have that triggers on the whole repo:

```
step_build = steps.ShellCommand(name='somebuildcommand',
        command=['some', 'build', 'command'],
        workdir="build/",
        description='some build command')

factory = util.BuildFactory()
# check out the source
factory.addStep(steps.Git(repourl='https://github.com/some/myrepo.git', mode='incremental'))
factory.addStep(step_build)

c['builders'] = []
c['builders'].append(
    util.BuilderConfig(name="runtests",
      workernames=["example-worker"],
      factory=factory))
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, figured this out myself, basically needed to configure scheduler and only trigger on "important" files, example below:

```
def file_is_important(change):
    if not change.files:
        return False
    for file in change.files:
        if file.startswith('important-dir/'):
            print 'detected important changes:', change.files
            return True
    return False

c['schedulers'] = []
c['schedulers'].append(schedulers.SingleBranchScheduler(
                            name="all",
                            fileIsImportant=file_is_important,
                            change_filter=util.ChangeFilter(branch='master'),
                            treeStableTimer=None,
                            builderNames=["builder"]))
```